# Variable return by statement expression or block

Tags: ios

A variable can return by statement expression:

```
_user = ({
    User *user = [[User alloc]init];
    user.name = @"Joe";
    user.age = 18;
    user;
});
```

or block:

```
_user = ^{
    User *user = [[User alloc]init];
    user.name = @"Joe";
    user.age = 18;
    return user;
}();
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages between them?

Comment: The `statement expression` run on the same process. And `block` will run on another process.

Comment: In this case the block will run on the same thread, as it is immediately executed after it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

And like you inserted first at variable you will have some return value that fill that declared variable.
At your second that is a block you just will run block of code, if you want a return statement you will need declare a block waiting for a block with.